# most of the code doesn't show up only the welcome message and "enter pin"?

Tags: c++, if-statement, codeblocks, getch

Assignment:

1. When you enter an incorrect number of digits( 3 or 5 digits pin number) a
   message should display “You have entered the incorrect pin number!!...you
   must enter a four digits pin number.”
2. By showing the message that was display previously the program should
   allow you to re-enter the correct number of digits.
3. The number of attempts should be three times.
4. When you have entered the correct number of digits a message should display
   “Your pin has been accepted!!”
5. Each time you enter any amount of pin number it must show in asterisk.

Code:

```
#include <conio.h>

#include <iostream>
//#include <cstdlib.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string pass = "";
  int attempts = 3;

  cout << "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^" << endl;
  cout << "< Welcome to The Bank     >" << endl;
  cout << "<                         >" << endl;
  cout << "< Please Enter Pin Below  >" << endl;
  cout << " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^" << endl;

  cout << "\nEnter Pin Number: " << endl;
  cin >> pass;

  // attempts= getch();
  while (attempts <= 3) {
    cout << "*";
    getch();
    attempts++;  // take this out and it display to infinity
                 // }

    if (pass == "1718") {
      cout << " lOGIN  IN..." << endl << endl;
      attempts = -1;
    }

    else {
      cout << "\nWRONT PIN-TRY AGAIN: " << endl << endl;
      attempts--;
      cout << " REMAINING ATTEMPTS: " << attempts << endl << endl;
    }

    if (attempts == 0) {
      cout << "Exceed the Pin attempts. Try Later. " << endl << endl;
    }

    if (attempts == -1) {
      cout << "********************************" << endl;
      cout << "*  Welcome to Magali's Bank    *\n";
      cout << "*  Select Option:              *\n";
      cout << "*    1. Check Balance          *\n";
      cout << "*    2. Withdraw               *\n";
      cout << "*    3. Deposit                *\n";
      cout << "*    4. Exit                   *\n";
      cout << "********************************\n";

      int balance = 500;
      float withdraw;
      float deposit;
      int user;

      cout << "Enter Number: ";
      cin >> user;

      while (user != 4) {
        switch (user) {
          case 1:
            cout << " Your balance is: " << balance << endl;
            break;

          case 2:
            cout << "Enter the amount you want withdraw: ";
            cin >> withdraw;
            balance = balance - withdraw;
            break;

          case 3:
            cout << "Enter the amount you want to deposit: ";
            cin >> deposit;
            balance = balance + deposit;
            break;

          default:
            cout << " Need to type 1 for Balance, 2 to Withdraw, 3 to Deposit "
                    "and 4 to Exit. ";
        }
        cout << "Enter Number: ";
        cin >> user;
      }
      cout << "\nTHANKS FOR USING THE SYSTEM!\n";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the input you are using. Also reduce your code a to a [repro].

Comment: I don't know the input your asking. Can I have an example?

Comment: `cin >> pass;` is asking the user for input. What are you typing in and are you pressing enter afterwards?

Comment: the pass = 1718. If the user types the password it will direct them to the bank menu. If not then it will ask for the correct pass which is for the  cout <<"Enter pin"; three times then exits. During those three tries, the remaining tries will show.

Comment: No, what I want to know is what you entered in the test run which didn't "*show most of the code*", so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: oh, well almost all the code. When I run it the user can only see the first welcome message and to enter pin.

Comment: You still didn't understand me. You ran the program. It shows you the welcome message and asks you to enter the pin. What did you enter before coming to the conclusion that your program doesn't work and posting here?

Comment: I input a bunch of numbers before I pressed enter to see if the number will show as a asterisk and it doesn't. Also when I input the correct pin it doesn't go to the second message which is the menu, it just exits.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lots of inefficiencies but as you requested. I'm only debugging only a part of it where you need to take input and display error.

```
string pass="";
int attempts=3;
const string pin = "1718";
//DO whatever you want 
//while loop to take input

while (attempts >0)
     {
         cout << "\nEnter Pin Number: " << endl;
         cin >> pass;
         for(auto i : pass)
            cout<<"*";
         if(pass == pin){
            attempts = 3;
            cout<<"Your Pin has been accepted.\n";
            break;}
        else{
        cout <<"\nWRONT PIN-TRY AGAIN: " << endl << endl;
       attempts--;
       cout << " REMAINING ATTEMPTS: " << attempts << endl << endl;
        }
    }

if (attempts == 0)
 {
 cout << "Exceed the Pin attempts. Try Later. "<< endl << endl;
 cout<<"Your account has been locked for a day .\n";
 exit(0);
 }
```

Comment out if you didn't understand any part.